# Ajax request, updating html using javascript but styling not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Sorry for the strange title, I am currently making a web page, when the page is loaded on a request I call the following two scripts in my 'head' tag to make a nice dynamic button effect.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

The user then can update their request on the page loaded in, I use AJAX to collect the information.

I then make a string for the new html with data from the return json object. The code is like the following but the += is in a loop.

```
htmlTag ='';                                 
htmlTag += '<div data-role="main" class="ui-content"> <div data-role="collapsible"><h5>'+ json_data[i] +'</h5></div></div>'
```

I then update a div putting its innerhtml as this string.
The html updates with the values i want but the css/jquery doesn't work with the button effects.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

It loads in the first time perfectly using these div classes uisng jinja.

Comment: how do you bind the button events originally?

Comment: I dont,  I just have the jquery link in the head, and use the divs, <div data-role="main" class="ui-content"> and  <div data-role="collapsible"> and it just does it for me. Sorry in advance for my lack of lingo, front end wouldn't be my specialty at all hahah. Cheers for the help though @hairmot

Answer (score 0):

The events which jquery mobile attaches are added on page load to specific elements. As you have added these elements with ajax, they will not have the events bound in the same way as they weren't present on page load.

You need to trigger the jquery mobile `pagecreate` method after you have added these dynamic elements to the DOM. This should bind them in the same way as they would have been if they were present originally.

[see api documentation here](https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)

Comment: So in my javascript function where I update the html with document.getElementById('dynamicDiv').innerHTML = htmlTag;                After ill use this? But the page has already been created? and now ive just made an ajax request? I dont want the page to reload

Comment: You are telling the page to act as if it had just been loaded, not actually reloading the page. Something like $('#dynamicDiv').html(htmlTag).trigger('pagecreate');